# Is there an AI that can play "One of these things is not like the other" (Sesame Street)?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

Refers to: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_of_These_Things_(Is_Not_Like_the_Others)

Some of the [actual games](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=one%20of%20these%20things%20is%20not%20like%20the%20others)

The idea is that there are four different objects, but one in particular stands out from the rest. I've always said that I didn't think AI would ever be able to
this, that this is something that kids instinctually understand that computers never would. But now I'm thinking maybe it might? Is there an AI that could identify the "different" object and explain why it chose it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of These Things (Is Not Like the Others): banana, apple, orange, shoe ?

*The item that does not belong in the group is "shoe."*

*The other three items, banana, apple, and orange, are all fruits commonly consumed as food. On the other hand, a shoe is not a fruit; it is a type of footwear typically worn on the feet. So, the shoe stands out as different from the others in terms of category and usage.*

Who do you think wrote this ?

---

Interestingly, the AI that did this has no reasoning capability (as confirmed by the creators), and instead assembles the words in a way that probabilistically matches the input question.

The lesson is that playing this game does not take any understanding, but just having met similar sentences in the past. IMO this strongly questions our own intelligence.

By the way, current AIs are also able to recognize these objects from the pictures.

---

Follow-up:

Is there another difference ?

*Yes, there is another difference between the items. The banana, apple, and orange are all natural objects, whereas a shoe is a man-made object. Fruits like bananas, apples, and oranges are produced by plants and occur naturally in the environment. In contrast, a shoe is a human invention, designed and manufactured for the purpose of protecting and covering the feet. So, in addition to the difference in category and usage, there is a distinction between the natural origin of the fruits and the artificial creation of the shoe.*

Comment: I don't understand. You say: "The lesson is that playing this game does not take any understanding" and then you say "Yes, there is another difference between the items [fruit vs. shoe, plus] The banana, apple, and orange are all natural objects, whereas a shoe is a man-made object. Fruits like bananas, apples, and oranges are produced by plants and occur naturally in the environment. In contrast, a shoe is a human invention..." this requires understanding, no?

Comment: "Who do you think wrote this ?" Staff working for Sesame Street wrote this. Or are you saying there is an AI that is creating instances of this game?

Comment: @ControlAltDel I believe this answer shows an interaction with chatGPT or a similar language model, playing the game.

Comment: @ControlAltDel: I only wrote all the parts in straight characters. Contrary to intuition, no understanding is needed. Just mimicking. Or call it "experience" if you prefer.

Comment: I think I get it now, thanks!